# Symfony 5.1 directory does not exist error

Tags: php, symfony

I try to rename in my public/assets directory my img directory to images but i got this error when i use any command in CLI.

**In FilesystemLoader.php line 92:

The "/home/boster/projet/symfony/rownd/assets/images" directory does not exist ("/home/boster/projet/symfony/rownd/assets/images").**

I use :

- php bin/console cache:clear
- php bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.global_clearer

I have the same bug in ClI and my navigator

Comment: Did you used twig `asset()` function somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I use it in my base.html.twig

Comment: Which kind of "bug" are you talking about? In the given file path, you are not doing anything in `public/assets`, but in a different folder